# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'- initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

**CODE**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
   return self;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2012-11-20 15:23:55.035 ReaderDeployment[5152:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Signature 0x7aa9de0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key drawSign.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b94022 0x155dcd6 0x1b93ee1 0x3b2022 0x323f6b 0x323edb 0x33ed50 0xa4f878 0xa4f8b3 0x1b95dea 0x1aff7f1 0x88326e 0x7291fc 0x729779 0x72999b 0x7329bc 0x72d818 0x949565 0x730857 0x7309bc 0x61bb 0x1b95e99 0x66514e 0x6650e6 0x70bade 0x70bfa7 0x70b266 0x68a3c0 0x68a5e6 0x670dc4 0x664634 0x1a7eef5 0x1b68195 0x1accff2 0x1acb8da 0x1acad84 0x1acac9b 0x1a7d7d8 0x1a7d88a 0x662626 0x2bed 0x2b65)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I am unable to understand the exception and the reason for the exception.Hence I am unable to eradicate the issue. Please help in understanding the exception and  solution.

Comment: See the "Related" section on the right?  Are you saying **none** of those answers gave you a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the class name with xib , It is caused by the your `ReaderDeployment` class or xib are not available in the project so just check it and give the right name..

for more details see this may you can get idea from this..

[this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 1):

Open the xib file in the interface builder. On the rightmost view open connections panel ( disk with an arrow) there will probably be an exclamation mark on the connection called "drawSign". Either remove or reconnect it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with paras joshi. Just check the class names again. Changing to the correct class names should resolve the problem. Or try reassigning the classes.